# Html text box height in percentage

Tags: css, sencha-touch, height, percentage

I am creating a html5 mobile apllication using Sencha Touch.

I want to specify the height of text box in percentage of screen size.I am aware that the percentage is calculated based on the size of its parent container.If i specify the height as x% in css the height will be different for different text boxes based on its position ie the height will be small if it is placed inside a div with height y%

I have also checked "em" but the default font size is 16px in all devices

Please suggest a solution(other than using media query)

Regards

Denny

Comment: Please post your code. :)

Comment: In sencha touch, there is `layout` config which has values like `hbox` and `vbox`. check the docs. might be helpful for you :).

Answer (score 0):

make this

http://jsfiddle.net/Fytmf/1/

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, #mything, #mything textarea {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mything">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="40">x</textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<input type="text" style="font-size: 80%;" />
```

It will change both text box and font size